# PHP code to present query result present as html, and add hyperlink to text that is a url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cell in a database $Data. It could contain any data. some of that data might contain a url.

Using mysql I need php to return the text out of the cell, hyperlinking anything that is a url. I found the preg_replace function elsewhere on Overflow but its not working.

Im trying to find code that will extract $Data then present $Data as text plus hyperlinked url.

I found this:

```
preg_replace('/\b(https?:\/\/(.+?))\b/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $text);
```

but a) its not working and b) I need a statement to extract $Data first

Comment: Why don't you post the code you're using instead of out-of-context fragments. That gives people a much better chance of helping.

Comment: "it's not working" has never helped anyone, anywhere in any situation. Certainly it does not help here. Please say exactly what is not working, what happens, why that is wrong and what you would expect instead. Together with the code you use and you have to post we might then work out together what your question here is.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The final statement as resolved by @Aitch was My final statement was <h3><?php $data = \preg_replace('/\b(https?:\/\/.+)\b/i', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $data);?><? echo $data ?></h3>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live regex says it works: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aqB (click on preg_replace on the right).

```
$data = \preg_replace('/\b(https?:\/\/.+)\b/i', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks Aitch. Worked brilliantly. My final statement was <h3><?php $data = \preg_replace('/\b(https?:\/\/.+)\b/i', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $data);?><? echo $data ?></h3>